# Is it possible to select/draw other figures other than rectangles or squares when creating .box files for tesseract?

Tags: machine-learning, ocr, tesseract, training-data, image-classification

I am trying to build and then train on a custom dataset to improve OCR of `tesseract`.
Please note that I have very few experience in ML, especially in neural networks.

The text on the images I am trying to recognize are these:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

As you can see the texts are warped and have one or more lines through it. The issue is that when I label each character to create the .box files I also get pieces of other characters because of the warping.

For instance:

[image]

So I was wondering if it could be possible to draw different types of bounding boxes.